# Querying firestore 2 subcollections deep

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how can I query a document two subcollections deep of the parent collection.

something like this gives me an error

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('col')
    .document(docId)
    .collection('anotherCol')
    .document(anotherDocId)
    .collection('yetAnotherCol')
    .snapshots()
```

This however works

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('col')
    .document(docId)
    .collection('anotherCol') 
    .snapshots()
```

Why doesn't the first one work?

**Edit**
More info

So in reality it doesn't give an error the query itself because it's not returning data, the error was coming from trying to read the content of the result.

To expound on this: I am running this in a StreamBuilder like so:

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('col')
          .document(docId)
          .collection('anotherCol')
          .document((anotherDocId)
          .collection('yetAnotherCol')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print('group length: ${snapshot.data.documents.length}');

        ....
      },
    );
```

So the stream above returns a length of 0 even if there are two documents at the end of the collection in the database.

The other thing I have realised is that I can't stream anotherDocId i.e. I can't read the content. I can get its id through `snapshot.data.documentID`, or read its content if I query the collection, in this case 'anotherCol', and then run it through a loop - which is the expected behavior. So again, things after the second collection in the query don't work as I hoped.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hello @DougStevenson, please see edit above for more info.

Comment: What exactly do you expect from the query?  Since we can't see the values of the variables you're using, nor the data in the subcollection they reference, there's nothing we can do.  Best I can tell - you're querying a collection with no documents in it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have tried the explain the scenario. Forexample Like I have mentioned above, if I run this stream `Firestore.instance
          .collection('col')
          .document(docId).snapshots()` I can access the properties of the document as expected through `snapshot.data['property']`. But I can't do the same for `Firestore.instance
          .collection('col')
          .document(docId)
          .collection('anotherCol')
          .document((anotherDocId).snapshots()` which is another collection deep.

Comment: I understand the scenario, but as I said before, since we can't see your variables or data, we can't tell what's going on.  Please edit the question to show the contents of the variables you're using (or better, just hard code all the strings), and also show the data in the database that you expect to get back.  We should be able to see that all the names of the collections and documents in the database match all the names you use in your code.

Comment: Ok @DougStevenson thanks for trying to help. Just tell me one thing: Is it possible or is the query not possible? As the last pointer, I get `The method '[]' was called on null.` if I try to access the property in the second scenario i.e `Firestore.instance .collection('col') .document(docId) .collection('anotherCol') .document((anotherDocId).snapshots()`

Comment: The query is possible.  You can nest subcollections like this.  You just need documents in the subcollection to query.

Comment: Please @DougStevenson I have explained this above. The documents are there. Not only did I put them there, but I can see them in the DB, and I can query (for the first subcollection) them well. Above I mention that I can query docs in the 1st sub-col but I can't stream the docs themselves directly, yet I could do this (stream a  doc directly) for the docs under the root collection. This is the difference. After the 2nd subdirectory - don't even bother nothing is returned. I would like you to be kind and share an online example with this scenario if you know any.

Comment: @DougStevenson. Well you were right, It had to do something with the variable `anotherDocId` above. It is a value I am streaming from another point of the database and directly inserting it as a document id. Apparently I had to attach `toString()` to it change it to a string. What confused me is that I was printing its runtime value with `.runtimeType` and it always showed that it was a string. Again, thanks for the help your assurance that it is possible made me look harder.